# How to use Bootstrap 5 for a typical home page layout instead of CSS?

Tags: bootstrap-5

CodePen https://codepen.io/david263/pen/zYNaoRQ shows an example simple home page layout that fits the browser viewport perfectly and centers some div content (choose Change View > Full Page View in CodePen to see the page clearly). But note the CSS style elements used to set div heights and the many Bootstrap 5 classes used to achieve vertical centering. It took several days to get this working, but it fails to use only simple Bootstrap 5 classes.

```
<header id=jumbo class="px-5 d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center bg-dark" style="height:70vh">
        <div class="row col-12 text-center text-light">
            <h1 class="font-weight-bold display-4">Vertically Centered Jumbo Content</h1>
            <h3 class="font-weight-bold">A great starter layout for a landing page</h3>
        </div>
</header>
```

My attempt to use the usual container, row, and col classes (see https://codepen.io/david263/full/xxgzLPj) failed to achieve the full height demonstrated by the first example.

```
<header id=jumbo class="container-fluid bg-dark">
    <div class="h-50 row align-items-center col-12 text-center text-light">
        <div class="col py-auto">
            <h1 class="font-weight-bold display-4">Vertically Centered Jumbo Content</h1>
            <h3 class="font-weight-bold">A great starter layout for a landing page</h3>
        </div>
    </div>
</header>
```

And these difficulties were encountered before adding a background image, which doesn't seem possible in Bootstrap 5 at all.

Don't get me wrong; I'm not opposed to using CSS when necessary. It's just that it's hard to tell exactly what the limits are for Bootstrap 5 so that custom CSS becomes necessary.

Many websites have a home page containing a large photo or video in the background, with text centered horizontally and vertically in the foreground, so this example represents something that is very often used. Surely such a frequent layout must be possible in Bootstrap 5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bootstrap isn't a silver bullet - its a framework (think of it as a chassis that you need build on top of).  Bootstrap offers a few "helper" classes so that one does not need to add a whole bunch of repetitive CSS .. but that's all it can do.  A clear understanding of CSS helps a lot too in using Bootstrap.

For example, the `h-50` class is only `height: 50%;` in CSS.  That's 50% of it's parent .. but your `<header id="jumbo"` does not have a height .. so 50% of what .. 0 .. is *unknown*?? *(This may vary from browser to browser)*

It's not clear what you're trying to achieve - but if you head on over to https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/examples/ you'll see a whole bunch of examples and starting points for you to get to where you need to be.   I think the [Cover](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/examples/cover/) example is a good spot to land on.  *(Once there, right click and "view page source" ...)*